# How to make this effect in AI or photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

[image]

Please give me an advice to create this effect to text as shown in the picture.

Comment: My answer on the duplicate would be the same answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately don't know any plugin, but in Photoshop you can smudge to a long stroke a small area that has the wanted colors. Requires a steady hand. Wacom tablet shines in thislike freehand works. Do the letters in different layers for easy composition and being able to redo individual letters if and when needed. Some letters need a copy to 2nd layer for overlaps. If you have a Wacom, check its bonus drawing program.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple you only need to have a brush with foreground and background jittering on and set the foreground and background